# Control process with long deadtime

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, control-theory, signal-processing

I am a programmer who lacks the mathematics side of things. I need help writing out a SOPDT equation and a Smith Predictor using simple math. I did not go to school for this and understand that there is probably more to it than simple math. 
My process has a long deadtime around 15-20 minutes before a change is seen. I've tried simple PI control but I tend to overshoot my setpoint quite a bit.
I'm using a PLC with ladder logic, the plc has every math function I would need to incorporate some model control. 
If anyone is interested in helping me I would likely pay.

Comment: Can you post the transfer function of your process (with parameters)?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest Model Predictive Control (MPC) for a system with a dead-line.
This control method will highly improve stability and reduces the error.

You can find an example of MPC comparison with PID at [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271477630_PID_versus_MPC_Performance_for_SISO_Dead-Time_Dominant_Processes).

More mathematical formulation at [here](http://dro.deakin.edu.au/eserv/DU:30112367/mohammadi-enhancinghuman-2018.pdf#page=65).

I should note that the mathematical formulation of MPC is larger than PID hence more complex.